# Trying to send automatic SMS from my app but getting error Unresolved function or method autoSend()

Tags: react-native

I have been trying to send automatic SMS with react-native-sms-android package and i constantly get an error. Unresolved function or method autoSend().

'''

```
const sendSMS = SmsAndroid.autoSend(
    phoneNumbers,
    message,
    (fail) => {
        console.log('Failed with this error: ' + fail);
    },
    (success) => {
        console.log('SMS sent successfully');
    },
);
```

'''

Comment: Did u link to android ?

Comment: I did everything according to documentation...